# VS: Unable to Create Website '...'. Found '

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7, webforms

I have a problem about to create a website.
This is the first time, when I use IIS manager. I have read it about in a book (E-commerce in Asp.net 3.5). I follow step by step the descriptions... but the Visual Studio 2010 drop up this error message: " Unable to Create Website 'http://www.example.com'. Found'
In the google I don't find the correct answer about it.

[Here is my VS error message printscreen](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/110502/VS_dont_find_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

[Here is my IIS configuration printscreen](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/110502/IIS_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Yes, the VS is **Run in Administrator mode**

Finally, sorry for my beginner englis :-)

Please help me I want to learn, today :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the www.example.com website from IIS manager? The error message means that the website is already exists (hence "found") and Visual Studio cannot create the website.

Comment: Yes, I deleted it. And the Visual Studio throw up the same errormessage :-(

Comment: How about creating a website, test.example.com, in Visual Studio?

Comment: `File/New Website -> Asp.net website` Then WebLocation in the list I choose the `Http`, and type in the follow line: `www.example.com`

Comment: I have used the follow configuration in IIS: [link](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/110502/IIS_config1_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png). Then I pinged the ecomerce.example.com in cmd(with Admin mode). But the cmd write out: Requist timed out, and the IP-Address was: 66.129.99.88 
Then, in the IIS Manager in the Actions tab I clikked on the Browse ecomerce.example.com on 127.0.0.1 And the FF dont find the page... maybe I have problem with IIS config?

Comment: It's just the DNS problem. ecomerce.example.com does not really exist on the Internet. Please open the "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host" in notepad. Then add "127.0.0.1 ecomerce.example.com" and save the file.

Comment: Thanks may be it will work, but I have an another problem with the VS... I am unhappy :-(

Comment: I had the same problem, although I did not have the 'Found' part of the message.  You have to make sure you delete the website from inside of IIS Manager and not from Windows Explorer. Recreate the folder name if you have to, and then delete it from IIS Manager. Don't know the reason why, but it worked for me.

Comment: Deleted entry from IIS and recreated but still same message. Then deleted 'Example.csproj.user' from the folder with the project. Reloaded the project from VS and worked!