# Frontpage server extensions install problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, frontpage-extensions

**[Here is the antenced of my story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856880/vs-unable-to-create-website-found)**

I've got a problem with the VS or IIS. I don't know.

**When in the Visual Studio 2010 I try to create website: throw up the follow errormessage:
Unable to create the Wet site'http://www.ecommerce.com'. The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installe.**

I download the Frontpage extension from here: http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1630

Then I read how can it install, but when the article write that:
To extend a Web site using HTML Administration pages on Windows, use the following steps:

```
Click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Microsoft SharePoint Administrator to open the Server Administration page.
In the list of virtual servers, click Extend next to the virtual server you want to extend.
In the Administrator box, type the user name for the administrator of the virtual server.
Click Submit.
```

**I don't find Microsoft SharePoint Administrator** **on my Windows 7 Profesionnal 64 bit**

or

You can extend a Web site by using the command-line tools, owsadm or owsrmadm. These tools are located in the "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\50\bin" folder. To extend a Web site, use the install operation, which takes the following parameters.

**I don't find the Web Server Extennsions dir** **on my Windows 7 Profesionnal 64 bit**

*I have read another article where write that, Use the Visual Studio DVD go to WCU dir and into the Web Server ... dir, but I don't find...*

**I download the FPSE and install with my local Administration account.
But the Visaul Studio Always says: The WEb server does not appear to haver FPSE installed.
How can I fix it? Install it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bad news (may not be so bad):** FPSE for IIS 7 and 7.5 are not supported.  Alternative is to use WebDav and here's an article explaining [how to migrate FPSE Sites to WebDAV](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/359/how-to-migrate-fpse-sites-to-webdav/).

**Good News (may not be so good due to licensing part):** As of December 18, 2010, [Ready-to-Run Software Inc](http://www.rtr.com/fpse/Win2008R2/). has created Microsoft FrontPage Server Extensions (FPSE) 2002 for IIS 7 and 7.5.

See this announcement from MS: [FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions for IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1630)

Comment: Using webdav, I see that you still can't connect to an .mdf file in the app_data folder - it says `The file "F:\app_data\mydb.mdf" is on a network path that is not supported for database files` - also, any code supplied via code files in app_code show as errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the FrontPage Server Extensions are installed, this error may occur because the _vti_bin virtual directory is not marked executable. To correct this problem, run the Internet Service Manager, select the Web server having the problem, and use the Check Server Extensions task. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984224%28v=vs.71%29.aspx