# "The Web server does not appear to have the FrontPage server extensions installed and iis6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-6, publish, frontpage, frontpage-extensions

I wanted to publish my website from visual studio but i got "The Web server does not appear to have the FrontPage server extensions installed" error;first I tried to install frontpage but because i didn't have microsoft share point in my administrative tools list and as here said:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858811/frontpage-server-extensions-install-problem),I tried to install webdav 7.5 version,(I believed my iis version was 7)but it gives me error that iis version 7 needs webdav version 7.5!!!
I have googled it and tried so many links more or less(because I couldn't find some parts of them in my computer),I tried enabling webdav and ...
such as:[this](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000293.htm)and [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis) 
but none helped.so I thought maybe I am going wrong,so due to this:[which is my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039941/determination-of-windows-server-and-iis),i think maybe i am using windows server 2003 and iis6,so i googled to install frontpage for iis6,[from here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2c522246-8450-408d-b907-197dfa0fdbb6.mspx?mfr=true),but I don't have such a thing "FrontPage 2002 Server Extensions" in turn windows features on or off,so what should I do?please help me to get out of this hell,should I upgrade iis6 to iis7?please help,i will be so thankful.
by the way my os is windows 7 64 bit,and I use visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

FrontPage server extensions (FSE) is a server side package that FrontPage and some other Microsoft applications use to upload files to web sites. FSE must be installed on the server in order for these applications to upload files. FSE has nothing to do with Microsoft desktop products directly. It is often installed on Apache systems, for example. cPanel has an option to install it, if you are using that to manage your server.

IIS should come with FSE already installed, AFAIK. That would certainly make sense, with it being a Microsoft product.

Comment: You have to install FSE on your server.